# How to loop over the groupby column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

My dataframe is like this

```
Numbers, user_id, time_stamp
1   2   2013-11-15 03:45:04
2   2   2013-11-29 03:45:04
3   2   2013-12-09 03:45:04
4   2   2013-12-25 03:45:04
5   2   2013-12-31 03:45:04
6   3   2014-01-08 03:45:04
7   3   2014-02-03 03:45:04
7   4   2014-02-03 03:45:04
```

I have to find the user_id who visits the website on three different days in at least one week period. 
I tried

```
def gr (group):
    for i in range(1, len(group)-2):
        print (group['time_stamp'].ix[i+2] - group['time_stamp'].ix[i] <= pd.Timedelta(days=7))

df.groupby('user_id').apply(gr)
```

It's showing some values correctly but then throwing KeyError: 3
How can I filter all the user_id's satisfying the criteria?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work. But it seems your example does not have any user_id which satisfies your condition.

```
(
    df.assign(year=df.time_stamp.dt.year,
              woy=df.time_stamp.dt.weekofyear,
              dow=df.time_stamp.dt.dayofweek)
    .groupby(['user_id','year','woy'])
    .filter(lambda x: x.dow.nunique()>=3)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should actually work except that `ix[i]` is trying to use the index label, not the integer position. Try `.iloc[i,:]` instead.

But you could use the built-in pandas function to do this more effeciently.

Allen gives one such example but if I read the problem correctly then the solution is not exactly correct -- you're looking for any continuous 7-day period, not just a specific week of the year.

I believe the following should work:

```
weekly_counts=df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('user_id').rolling('7d')['user_id'].count().rename('count')
weekly_max=weekly_counts.groupby(level='user_id').max()
weekly_max[weekly_max>=3].index
```